# redis hmset exception with 50 MB value

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I'm trying to create a hash with a 50MB value.

This fails every time with the following exception

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 32 while writing to socket. Broken pipe
```

From reading up on the error I find that redis' size limit is 512mb, however the value I'm setting is only 50mb.

Why I'm I getting this?

Comment: 50 millibits is pretty small. Do you mean 50MB (megabytes)? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: Yes, megabytes. Fixing that.